# JHipster/React - Get data from server anonymously (before login)

Tags: java, spring, reactjs, jhipster

I have generated a JHipster application (client side using ReactJs).
I'm trying to create an anonymous request to server to get data without authentication, but I'm receiving

```
{
    "error": "unauthorized",
    "error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
}
```

I'm using gateway and game service on server side. I've added to gateway SecurityConfiguration.java file

```
.and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/api/published-games").permitAll()
```

and to the game service SecurityConfiguration.java file

```
.and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/api/published-games").permitAll()
```

but still getting unauthorized error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must configure authorized endpoints in gateway's `application*.yml` under `jhipster.gateway.authorized-microservices-endpoints` property. This is the source of configuration for `AccessControlFilter`. Don't forget to update it in registry.

In your case it should be:

```
gateway:
    authorized-microservices-endpoints: # Access Control Policy, if left empty for a route, all endpoints will be accessible
        game: /api,/api/published-games
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't write all your SecurityConfiguration.java.

You need to specify a entire endpoint path permitted to all:

```
.and()
     .authorizeRequests()
     .antMatchers("/app/test").permitAll()
     ....
```

You need to implement the service like you can see into the method LogoutResource.logout, some like this:

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/app")
    public class PublicResource {

      private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PublicResource.class);
      private final UserService userService;
      public PublicResource(UserService userService) {

        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getATest(Pageable pageable) {               
        Map<String, String> logoutDetails = new HashMap<>();
        logoutDetails.put("A", "One");
        logoutDetails.put("B", "Two");        
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(logoutDetails);
    }
...
```